# Use env variable which is set in subdirectory htaccess and accessed in root htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm setting a variable "require_auth" in a .htaccess inside a directory and  using the variable in another .htaccess inside root.But it throws a 401 error when I visit the earlier directory URL.

So for the root directory, I have the following code in .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/membership/ require_auth=true
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

And in a directory inside the root "/data", I have another .htaccess with this code

```
SetEnv require_auth true
AuthType basic
AuthName "Only Admin Allowed"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd_wpadmin
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

But when I access the URL "/data", I get this error 401

> Unauthorized
>   This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Currently im using this code for Apache
 Authentication..

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Name to be displayed
AuthUser File /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require user  username
```

Then add .htpasswd file in /etc/httpd/.htpasswd

Finally the authenticated users list you can add the users to the .htpasswd file by using the below command

```
htpasswd -cb /etc/httpd/.htpasswd username
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: This is the basic code for authentication. But I want to protect a route and a directory, so I'm doing it by setting a env variable. Can you help with that?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow   Check this one...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073752/apache-htaccess-applying-basic-authentication-conditionally-based-on-environm

Comment: No. Doesn't help. Basically I need to access the env variable across multiple htaccess. it doesn't explain that